# Specializing non-type template of a type that contains itself

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-specialization

Given the code below, how would I specify a non-type template parameter for `Pathfinder` in order to declare the size of the `Pathfinder::Node` member `std::array<Node*, 8> neighbors` array (hard-coded to 8 in this use) so that the neighbor can be of any size (realistically specialized to 4 for mazes, 6 for hex-tiles a la modern Civilization games, or 8 for tiles sets a la Rogue-likes.)?

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "Engine/Math/IntVector2.hpp"

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

class Pathfinder {
public:

    constexpr static uint8_t PATHFINDING_SUCCESS = 0;
    constexpr static uint8_t PATHFINDING_NO_PATH = 1;
    constexpr static uint8_t PATHFINDING_GOAL_UNREACHABLE = 2;
    constexpr static uint8_t PATHFINDING_INVALID_INITIAL_NODE = 3;
    constexpr static uint8_t PATHFINDING_PATH_EMPTY_ERROR = 4;
    constexpr static uint8_t PATHFINDING_UNKNOWN_ERROR = 5;

    struct Node {
        std::array<Node*, 8> neighbors{nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr};
        Node* parent{nullptr};
        float f = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
        float g = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
        IntVector2 coords = IntVector2::ZERO;
        bool visited = false;
    };

    void Initialize(int width, int height) noexcept;
    const std::vector<const Pathfinder::Node*> GetResult() const noexcept;
    void ResetNavMap() noexcept;

    template<typename Viability, typename Heuristic, typename DistanceFunc>
    uint8_t AStar(const IntVector2& start, const IntVector2& goal, Viability&& viable, Heuristic&& h, DistanceFunc&& distance) {
        auto* initial = GetNode(start);
        if(!initial) {
            return PATHFINDING_INVALID_INITIAL_NODE;
        }
        initial->g = 0.0f;
        initial->f = static_cast<float>(std::invoke(h, start, goal));

        const auto comp = [](const Node* a, const Node* b) { return a->f < b->f;  };
        std::priority_queue<Node*, std::vector<Node*>, decltype(comp)> openSet(comp);
        std::vector<Node*> closedSet{};

        const auto IsGoalInClosedSet = [&closedSet, goal]()->bool {
            const auto found = std::find_if(std::cbegin(closedSet), std::cend(closedSet), [goal](const Node* a)->bool { return a->coords == goal; });
            return found != std::cend(closedSet);
        };
        const auto IsNodeVisited = [](const Node* a)-> bool {
            return a->visited;
        };
        const auto EveryNodeSearched = [this, &closedSet]()->bool {
            return _navMap.size() == closedSet.size();
        };
        const auto IsGoalUnreachable = [&closedSet](const Node* current)->bool {
            unsigned char visited_count = 0;
            const auto is_in_closed_set = std::find(std::begin(closedSet), std::end(closedSet), current) != std::end(closedSet);
            for(const Node* neighbor : current->neighbors) {
                if(neighbor == nullptr) {
                    ++visited_count;
                    continue;
                }
                if(is_in_closed_set) {
                    ++visited_count;
                }
            }
            return visited_count >= 8;
        };
        const auto IsNeighborValid = [&closedSet](const Node* current)->bool {
            if(current != nullptr) {
                const auto found = std::find(std::begin(closedSet), std::end(closedSet), current);
                return found == std::end(closedSet);
            }
            return false;
        };
        const auto IsNeighborTraversable = [this](const Node* neighbor)->bool {
            if(neighbor == nullptr) {
                return false;
            }
            const auto n_idx = neighbor->coords.y * _dimensions.x + neighbor->coords.x; 0 > n_idx || n_idx >= _dimensions.x * _dimensions.y;
            const auto is_inside_map = n_idx < _dimensions.x * _dimensions.y;
            return is_inside_map;
        };
        openSet.push(initial);
        while(true) {
            if(openSet.empty()) {
                return PATHFINDING_GOAL_UNREACHABLE;
            }
            Node* current = openSet.top();
            openSet.pop();
            closedSet.push_back(current);
            current->visited = true;
            if(current->coords == goal) {
                break;
            }
            for(const auto neighbor : current->neighbors) {
                if(!(IsNeighborValid(neighbor) && IsNeighborTraversable(neighbor))) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(!std::invoke(viable, neighbor->coords)) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(!IsNodeVisited(neighbor)) {
                    openSet.push(neighbor);
                }
                const float tenativeGScore = current->g + std::invoke(distance, current->coords, neighbor->coords);
                if(tenativeGScore < neighbor->g) {
                    neighbor->parent = current;
                    neighbor->g = tenativeGScore;
                    neighbor->f = neighbor->g + std::invoke(h, neighbor->coords, goal);
                }
            }
        }
        if(!IsGoalInClosedSet() && !_path.empty()) {
            return PATHFINDING_GOAL_UNREACHABLE;
        }
        if(!IsGoalInClosedSet() && _path.empty()) {
            return PATHFINDING_NO_PATH;
        }
        if(IsGoalInClosedSet() && !_path.empty()) {
            const Node* end = _path.front();
            if(end) {
                if(const Node* p = end) {
                    _path.clear();
                    while(p->parent) {
                        _path.push_back(p);
                        p = p->parent;
                    }
                }
            }
            return PATHFINDING_SUCCESS;
        }
        if(IsGoalInClosedSet() && _path.empty()) {
            if(const Node* end = closedSet.back()) {
                if(const Node* p = end) {
                    _path.clear();
                    _path.push_back(p);
                    while(p->parent) {
                        _path.push_back(p);
                        p = p->parent;
                    }
                    return PATHFINDING_SUCCESS;
                }
            }
        }
        return PATHFINDING_UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    }

    template<typename Viability, typename DistanceFunc>
    uint8_t Dijkstra(const IntVector2& start, const IntVector2& goal, Viability&& viable, DistanceFunc&& distance) {
        return AStar(start, goal, viable, [](const IntVector2&, const IntVector2&)->int { return 0; }, distance);
    }

protected:
private:
    const Pathfinder::Node* GetNode(int x, int y) const noexcept;
    Pathfinder::Node* GetNode(int x, int y) noexcept;
    const Pathfinder::Node* GetNode(const IntVector2& pos) const noexcept;
    Pathfinder::Node* GetNode(const IntVector2& pos) noexcept;
    const std::array<const Pathfinder::Node*, 8> GetNeighbors(int x, int y) const noexcept;
    void SetNeighbors(int x, int y) noexcept;

    std::vector<const Node*> _path{};
    std::vector<Node> _navMap{};
    IntVector2 _dimensions{};
    static inline bool already_initialized{false};
};
```

Comment: Something like `template<size_t NeighborCount> class Pathfinder { ... };` should do fine. Just pass it all the way through to the interior of the `Node` struct.

Comment: This is a lot of code for the question you're asking. Can you try to make a more minimal example?

Comment: Making `Pathfinder` into a template will require moving ***all methods***, `Initialize()`, `GetResult()`, and all the rest of them, into this header file. You should consider some serious redesign of this entire class hierarchy.

Comment: @NathanPierson Would the `NeighborCount` be visible inside `Node`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Are you suggesting I consider a redesign if I go the template route, or in general?

Comment: @cigien it looks like a lot because of the templated Astar implementation, but that is required to show a complete example of `Node`'s use.

Comment: A minimal example means removing all the code that's not relevant to the issue you're having. Is your question specific to your implementation of `Astar` and `Node`?

Comment: If you go the template route, unless you're fine with moving ***all*** the code into this header file, you have no choice but to redesign the whole thing.